# Is there a way to generate correlated Binomial, Gaussian and Poisson variables in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, variables, random, correlation

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically generate random variables which are correlated (even a Binomial with a Gaussian, not only variables belonging to the same family). The variables need to belong to the Gaussian, Poisson or Binomial family. Here, there is a not very automatic way to create variables which are correlated within the same family.

```
x1<-rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
index<-sort(sample(1:100, 10, replace=F))
x2<-x1
for(i in 1:length(index)){
  if(x2[index[i]]==0){
    x2[index[i]]<-1
  }else{
    x2[index[i]]<-0
  }
}
normal<-as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 100, mu = c(1,2), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.6, 0.6,1), nrow = 2, byrow = T)))
x3<-normal$V1
x4<-normal$V2
x5.1<- rpois(100, 0.5)
x5.2<-rpois(100, 2)
x5.3<-rpois(100, 1)
x5<- x5.1+x5.2
x6<-x5.1+x5.3
x<-as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6))
cor(x)
```

My goal is to create a dataset with mixed-type correlated variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that can generate or simulate data in the way you need, and beyond into more complex correlation structures. The [simstudy](https://kgoldfeld.github.io/simstudy/index.html) package provides `genCorData()` `genCorGen()`, and `addCorGen()` to simulate gaussian data with a given correlation structure and also to produce data simulated from other distributions. Here's some correlated data simulated from a poisson distribution, for example, taken from the package's [vignette on correlated data](https://kgoldfeld.github.io/simstudy/articles/correlated.html):

```r
l <- c(8, 10, 12) # lambda for each new variable

dx <- genCorGen(1000, nvars = 3, params1 = l, 
                dist = "poisson", rho = .3, 
                corstr = "cs", wide = TRUE)
dx

##         id V1 V2 V3
##    1:    1  5 16 13
##    2:    2  9  9  6
##    3:    3  7 11 18
##    4:    4 11 14 12
##    5:    5 10  8 15
##   ---              
##  996:  996  3  2  5
##  997:  997  6 14 11
##  998:  998  6  8 12
##  999:  999 10 12 11
## 1000: 1000  9  9 12
```

A related package that might be of interest is [faux](https://debruine.github.io/faux/).